# How to show a function taking the form as $F(x,y) = 0$ is a contraction mapping?

Tags: probability, fixed-point-theorems

Let $\Phi (x)$ be the cumulative distribution function of the standard normal distribution. Given $x_0$, $x_1 = \Phi(x_0-x_1)$.If $x_n$ is given,   $x_{n+1} = \Phi(x_{n}-x_{n+1})$(By drawing a graph, $\lim_{n \to \infty}{x_n} = 1/2$, for all $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$).

My question is how to show that $\lim_{n \to \infty}{x_n}$ exists and is unique in the sense that it doesn't depend on the value of $x_0$ by contraction mapping principle.

The problem is that I don't know how to deal with the functions in the form of $F(x,y) = 0$, which can't be converted explicitly to the form $y = f(x)$. A general method is especially welcome.

Comment: It only needs to be a contraction in the 'fixed-point' parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that the function $F(x,y)$ is continuously differentiable and that the partial derivative $F_y $ never turns to $0$: 
$$F\in C^1(\mathbb R^2),\qquad F_y(x,y)\ne 0 \quad \forall (x,y)\in\mathbb  R^2 \tag1 $$
 Then $F_y$ has constant sign, which implies that for any fixed $x$ the equation $F(x,y)=0$ has *at most one* solution. To ensure that *there is* a solution, we should check that 
$$\forall x\in\mathbb R \ \text{ the function } y\mapsto F(x,y) \ \text{takes positive and negative values} \tag2 $$
If (1) and (2) hold, then the equation $F(x,y)=0$ defines a function $y=f(x)$ with $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$.

The 1-dimensional case of [Implicit Function theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem) (unfortunately not spelled out on Wikipedia explicitly) says that $f$ is continuously differentiable and its derivative can be computed as 
$$f'(x)=-\frac{F_x}{F_y}$$
Therefore, to apply the contraction mapping theorem to $f$, we remains to check that 
$$|F_x|\le \lambda |F_y| \quad \text{ everywhere } \tag3$$

---

All of the above is easy to carry out for the function $F(x,y)=y-\Phi(x-y)$ in your example. The value of $\lambda$ turns out to be something mildly entertaining, like $1/(1+\sqrt{2\pi})$.

Comment: Great! Tons of thanks.